Not show product list in used Odoo mobile framework app
Not shows product list on screen when inserted products in sqlite from used Odoo mobile framework app, inserted from Odoo erp version 10.0
use API 30, android version 11 emulator
But shows product list on screen use android version 10
why not show on android version 11 emulator or android phone?
argsProduct.add(jsonArray); String productResponse = productProduct.getServerDataHelper().callMethodOdErp("get_product_ids_all_mobile", argsProduct); ResUsers users = new ResUsers(getContext(), null); ODataRow userInfo = users.browse(null,"id = ?",new String[]{user().getUserId().toString()}); 
try { 
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(productResponse); 
    JSONArray productListResult = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result"); 
    JSONObject updateObject = new JSONObject(productListResult.get(0).toString()); 
    JSONObject insertObject = new JSONObject(productListResult.get(1).toString()); 
    JSONObject totalObject = new JSONObject(productListResult.get(2).toString()); 
    JSONArray updateList = updateObject.getJSONArray("update"); 
    JSONArray insertList = insertObject.getJSONArray("insert"); 
    JSONArray totalList = totalObject.getJSONArray("total"); int jsonObjectSize = 0;
    if(totalList.length() > 0)
                jsonObjectSize = totalList.getJSONObject(0).getInt("total");
            if (updateList.length() > 0) {
                int counter = 0;
                List<Integer> tempIds = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < updateList.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject productObj = updateList.getJSONObject(i);
                    tempIds.add(productObj.getInt("id"));
                    counter ++;
                    if(counter>399) {
                        boolean result = call(tempIds, userInfo.getString("lang"), jsonObjectSize, "update");
                        tempIds.clear();
                        counter = 0;
                        if(result == false) {
                            this.cancel(true);
                            if (isCancelled()) break;
                        }
                    }

                }
                call(tempIds, userInfo.getString("lang"), jsonObjectSize, "update");
            }

            if (insertList.length() > 0) {
                int counter = 0;
                List<Integer> tempIds = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < insertList.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject productObj = insertList.getJSONObject(i);
                    tempIds.add(productObj.getInt("id"));
                    counter ++;
                    if(counter>399) {
                        boolean result = call(tempIds, userInfo.getString("lang"), jsonObjectSize, "insert");
                        tempIds.clear();
                        counter = 0;
                        if(result == false) {
                            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_dashboard_goto_today).setEnabled(true);
                            this.cancel(true);
                            if (isCancelled()) break;
                        }
                    }

                }
                call(tempIds, userInfo.getString("lang"), jsonObjectSize, "insert");
            }

